# (LIST . VALUES) is not a proper list

Tags: common-lisp

Here is a sample code :

```
(defun my-test (&rest values)
  (macrolet ((my-macro (v)
               `(list ,@v)))
    (print values)
    (my-macro values)))

(my-test 1 2 3 4)
;; The goal is to obtain : (1 2 3 4).
```

When I execute last line, it prints `(1 2 3 4)`, then the function fails.
When I execute the defun or try to execute last line, I get the following warning/error (resp.) :

```
; in: DEFUN MY-TEST
;     (MY-PACKAGE::MY-MACRO VALUES)
; ==>
;   (LIST . VALUES)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   (LIST . VALUES) is not a proper list.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
```

Why does it fails ?

Comment: I know that changing `list ,@v` to `,@v` do the trick to obtain the good result, but I do not understand why I cannot use `list`; and on my real code I must have symbols before the `,@v` term.

Comment: 'values' is a symbol, not a list. I doubt ',@v' works alone. If you change the macrolet by an 'flet', then 'v' would be bound the evaluation of 'values', a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macro transform code and it does not know anything about the runtime values, only the literal code. Eg.

```
(cond (p1 e1) (p2 e2) (t e3))
```

Turns into

```
(if p1
    e1
    (if p2
        e3))
```

And we really don't know `p1` is at this moment. Now look at your code:

```
(defun my-test (&rest values)
  (macrolet ((my-macro (v)
               `(list ,@v)))
    (print values)
    (my-macro values)))
```

So the macro is expanded when `my-test` is created. Could you please tell me how `my-macro` is going to expand `(my-macro values)` if not `(list . values)`?
`(list . values)` is not valid Common Lisp and that is the source of your error.

You should perhaps do this without macros. eg. just use `values` works fine. For calling a function with a list as the argument you can use `apply`. To copy a list, which is not needed, you could use `copy-list` or `copy-tree`

Comment: I was negligent about the "not-runtime" property of macros, thank you for your answer.
About the fact I should maybe not use a macro, I think it is because it is a XY problem. I am going to open a new question about this.

Comment: For people interested : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52797673/9614866
So apply is indeed a good solution. Thank you again. <3