# Function with rest arguments calling a function with rest arguments

Tags: common-lisp

Let us suppose we have a function `func1` :

```
(defun func1 (&rest values)
  ; (do something with values...)
  (loop for i in values collect i))
```

Now, we have a function `func2` which calls `func1` :

```
(defun func2 (&rest values)
  ; (do something with values...)
  (func1 ???))
```

What should I put instead of `???` to "copy" all the parameters of `func2`'s `values` to `func1`'s `values` ?

For instance, I would have the following behavior :

```
(func2 1 2 3 4) ; result is (1 2 3 4) and not ((1 2 3 4)).
```

In [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52796579/9614866) I tried to do something like this :

```
(defun func2 (&rest values)
  (macrolet ((my-macro (v)
               `(list ,@v)))
    (func1 (my-macro values))))
```

But the defun cannot get the value because it is not runtime. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52796954/9614866), he suggested that I use `apply`, but this function takes a `&rest` parameter too, so it doesn't solve my problem...

If possible, I would rather **avoid to change the prototype of both functions, and the behavior of `func1`**.

Comment: It works, thank you ! :D
I'm ashamed, I counfounded `funcall` and `apply` and forgot `apply` took a list as argument. Solved. <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In common lisp, it has to be

```
(apply #'func1 values) ;; since `func1` has to be looked up in function namespace
```

remember, Clojure and Racket/Scheme are Lisp1, and common lisp is Lisp2.

**Alternative solution (just for the sake)**

I was asking myself, how to get it done without `apply` - just for the sake.
The problem with

```
`(func2 ,@values)
```

is, that if e.g.

```
 (func2 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5)
```

is called, the `values` variable is `((1 2 3) (4) 5)`
But when it is spliced into `(func1 ,@values)`, what is created is
`(func1 (1 2 3) (4) 5)`. But if we compare this with the `func2` call,
it should be rather `(func1 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5)` which is perhaps not possible, because when `(func2 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5)` is called -
in the lisp manner - the arguments of `func2` are each evaluated, before they enter the function body of `func2`, so we end up with `values` as a list of already evaluated arguments, namely `((1 2 3) (4) 5)`.

So somehow, concerning the arguments for `func1` in the last expression, we are **one evaluation-step offbeat**.

But there is a solution with **quote**, that we manage to quote each of the arguments before giving it to `func1` in the last expression, to **"synchronize"** the `func1` function call - to let the arguments' evaluation pause for one round.

So my first aim was to generate a new `values` list inside the `func2` body where each of the values list's argument is quoted (this is done in the let-binding).
And then at the end to splice this `quoted-values` list into the last expression: `(func1 '(1 2 3) '(4) '5)` which can be regarded as equivalent to `(func1 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5)` for this kind of problems / for this kind of calls.
This was achieved by this code:

```
(defun func2 (&rest vals)
  (let ((quoted-values (loop for x in vals
                                     collect `',x)))
    ; do sth with vals here - the func2 function -
    (eval `(func1 ,@quoted-values))))
```

This is kind of a macro (it creates code btw. it organizes new code) but executed and created in run-time - not in pre-compile time. Using an `eval` we execute that generated code on the fly.

And like `macroexpand-1`, we can look at the result - the code - to which the `func1` expression "expands", by removing `eval` around it - I call it `func2-1`:

```
(defun func2-1 (&rest vals)
  (let ((quoted-values (loop for x in vals
                                     collect `',x)))
    ; do sth with vals here - the func2 function -
    `(func1 ,@quoted-values)))
```

And if we run it, it returns the last expression as code immediately before it is evluated in the `func2` version:

```
(func2-1 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5)
;; (FUNC1 '(1 2 3) '(4) '5) ;; the returned code
;; the quoted arguments - like desired!
```

And this happens if we call it using `func2` (so with evaluation of the `func1` all:

```
(func2 (list 1 2 3) (list 4) 5) 
;; ((1 2 3) (4) 5)  ;; the result of (FUNC1 '(1 2 3) '(4) '5)
```

So I would say this is exactly what you desired!

Answer (score 3):

**lists vs. spread arguments**

In Common Lisp it is good style to pass lists as lists and not as *spread* arguments:

```
(foo (list 1 2 3))   ; better interface

(foo 1 2 3)          ; interface is not so good
```

The language has been defined in a way that efficient function calling can be used by a compiler and this means that the number of arguments which can be passed to a function is limited. There is a standard variable which will tell us how many arguments a particular implementation supports:

This is LispWorks on my Mac:

```
CL-USER 13 > call-arguments-limit
2047
```

Some implementations allow much larger number of arguments. But this number can be as low as 50 - for example ABCL, Common Lisp on the JVM, allows only 50 arguments.

**Computing with argument lists**

But sometimes we want the arguments as a list and then we can use the `&rest` parameter:

```
(lambda (&rest args)
  (print args))
```

This is slightly in-efficient, since a list will be consed for the arguments. Usually Lisp tries to avoid to cons lists for arguments - they will be passed in registers or on the stack - if possible.

If we know that the argument list will not be used, then we can give the compiler a hint to use stack allocation - if possible:

```
(lambda (&rest args)
  (declare (dynamic-extent args))
  (reduce #'+ args))
```

In above function, the list of arguments can be deallocated when leaving the function - because the argument list is no longer used then.

If you want to pass these arguments to another function you can use `FUNCALL` and usually more useful `APPLY`:

```
(lambda (&rest args)
  (funcall #'write (first args) (second args) (third args)))
```

or more useful:

```
(lambda (&rest args)
  (apply #'write args))
```

One can also add additional arguments to `APPLY` before the list to apply:

```
CL-USER 19 > ((lambda (&rest args)
                (apply #'write
                       (first args)               ; the object
                       :case :downcase            ; additional args 
                       (rest args))
                (values))
              '(defun foo () 'bar)
              :pretty t
              :right-margin 15)
(defun foo ()
  'bar)
```